# How to combine multiple words into a sentence with RxJava2?

Tags: java, stream, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Basically, I have a stream of words `Observable<String>`

What I want is to accumulate them, emitting nothing until I have a ".".
When I have a "." I want to emit the whole sentence. And so on until the stream is completed.

```
1) The -> nothing, accumulated
2) quick -> nothing, accumulated
3) brown -> nothing, accumulated
4) fox -> nothing, accumulated
5) jumps -> nothing, accumulated
6) over -> nothing, accumulated
7) the -> nothing, accumulated
8) lazy -> nothing, accumulated
9) dog. -> emit the whole sentence, clear accumulator
```

scan, reduce - looks similar, but not exactly, not sure

Comment: There is the extension operator [bufferUntil](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferuntil) you can use collect until the string contains the punctuation, then join the list of strings into one string.

Comment: Sorry for prev comment, did not notice a link in your answer, thanks for a suggestion - will look into it..

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and I will make the whole question answered @akarnokd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the extension operator [bufferUntil](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferuntil) you can use collect until the string contains the punctuation, then join the list of strings into one string:

```java
Flowable.fromArray("The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps",
    "over", "the", "lazy", "dog.",
    "This", "sentence", "is", "false.")
.compose(FlowableTransformers.bufferUntil(v -> v.endsWith(".")))
.map(list -> Strings.join(" ", list))
.test()
.assertResult(
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    "This sentence is false."
);
```